# Get all Form Collection values where Checkbox checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

View is as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCreditLeave", "AdminLeaveCredit"))
{
    <div id="Container">
        <table>
            <tr style="background-color:#A9DDFF;color:Black;">
                <td>Select</td>
                <td>Staff Code</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Designation</td>
                <td>AL</td>
                <td>CL</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var person in Model.Empdetailslist)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid" value="@person.staffcode"  id="chk"  />
                    </td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.staffcode, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:180px; text-align:center" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.name, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:180px; text-align:center" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.designation, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:180px; text-align:center" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.ALLeave, new { style = "width:180px; text-align:center" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.CLLeave, new { style = "width:180px; text-align:center" })</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
}
```

First column is a Checkbox and I am showing ten rows.

Second column is a TextBox.

There is a Save button. On click of Save button, I want to pick values of second column from the Form Collection where Checkbox is checked.

How to do this?

Comment: Can the answer use jquery?

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes do not post back so on post back `sid` will contain an array of the original `staffcode` values. However your code does not make a lot of sense since your have a textbox for `staffcode` but because you use a `foreach`  loop instead of a required `for` loop it will not work anyway (and you have lots of invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh. You mean I should use For loop instead of foreach and names should be like staffcode[i] ?

Comment: What you need is a view model containing a (say) `bool IsSelected` property. Then in the view use a `for` loop - `for ( int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected) ... }` and post back your collection of view models (forget using `FormCollection`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Though I got some idea, it would really help if you elaborate and post as answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Waiting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do this with a simplified example.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mcl2YI)

**Model**

```
public class AModel
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }            
    public string staffcode { get; set; }           
    public bool Checked { get; set; }          
}
```

Note the `Checked` property

View for loop

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Empdetailslist.Count; i++)
{
   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Empdetailslist[i].Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Empdetailslist[i].staffcode)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m = Model.Empdetailslist[i].Checked)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model[i].Name
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Note the `for` loop instead of `foreach` to enable model binding and the hidden fields to allow the values to be posted back to the controller

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

**Controller post**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCreditLeave(YourModel model)
{
   // property will be populated in model.Empdetailslist

    return View(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your View like this,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCreditLeave", "AdminLeaveCredit"))
{
    <div id="Container">
        <table>
            <tr style="background-color:#A9DDFF;color:Black;">
                <td>Select</td>
                <td>Staff Code</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Designation</td>
                <td>AL</td>
                <td>CL</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var person in Model.Empdetailslist)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid" value="@person.staffcode"  id="@person.id"  />
                    </td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.staffcode, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:180px; text-align:center", id="staffcode_@person.id" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.name, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:180px; text-align:center", id="name_@person.id" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.designation, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:180px; text-align:center", id="designation_@person.id" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.ALLeave, new { style = "width:180px; text-align:center", id="ALLeave_@person.id" })</td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => person.CLLeave, new { style = "width:180px; text-align:center", id="CLLeave_@person.id" })</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
        <input type="button" onclick="SavePersons();" />
}
```

Use this code to get all selected person objects in an array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SavePersons() {
    var chkArr = document.getElementsByName('sid');
    var selectedPersonsArr = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<chkArr.length; i++) {
        if(chkArr[i].checked == true) {
            var tmpPerson = new Object();
            tmpPerson.id = chkArr[i].id;
            tmpPerson.staffcode = document.getElementById('staffcode'+chkArr[i].id).value;
            tmpPerson.name = document.getElementById('name'+chkArr[i].id).value;
            tmpPerson.designation = document.getElementById('designation'+chkArr[i].id).value;
            tmpPerson.ALLeave = document.getElementById('ALLeave'+chkArr[i].id).value;
            tmpPerson.CLLeave = document.getElementById('CLLeave'+chkArr[i].id).value;
            selectedArr.push(tmpPerson);
        }
    }
    // Now array 'selectedPersonsArr' contains all selected Person objects
    // here you can send these objects to your controller through AJAX
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: After getting the checkboxes, how to get the Form value of a column related to this checkbox?

Comment: I want to get the corresponding values in Controller.

Comment: Yes. Is any correction needed in View code? When I have all the checked checkbox names using javascript, how to pick corresponding value in controller code?

Comment: Yes checked. Thanks. Is there a way without javascript code? Like Stepehen suggested, it should return ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, that will be a very easy solution then, you just need to add a boolean `IsSelected` property to your `Person` class and use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)` instead of `<input type="checkbox" />` element. And at the end just submit the form to your `[httppost]` action method, you will get your viewmodel back with changed values.

Comment: But how will IsSelected become true or false based on checkbox state?

Comment: Yes, your action method will automatically get updated values of `checkbox` as `form` gets submitted along with values of all input elements.